# Regex any string with max length

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, where-clause

I'm trying to make a mysql-regex SQL that wil find any strings with a maximum length - i can do it in javascrtip, php and so on - but for some reason i can get it to work in mysql

**Example strings:**

1. a12
2. a123
3. a1234
4. a12345
5. a123456

So lets say i want my regex to hit ANY strings with 4 or less in length - so in the example's above my regex should hit 1 & 2.

The code below works perfectly when trying to hit any strings above a certain length, but i can not get it to work with strings below a certain length.

```
([a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{20,}
```

i obviously tried to do

```
([a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,6}
```

but doesnt work for some reason

Comment: Why not just use the `length()` function if that is what you care about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]{0,3}$
```

This matches on an a string made of an alphabetic character followed by 0 to 3 alphanumeric characters. One important thing is to match on the entire string: that's what anchors `^` (beginning of the string) and `$` (end of the string) do.